# Make user able to click buttons of powerpoint content app during presentation mode

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office365api

We are developing an office powerpoint content app. During the slide show (presentation mode) the user needs to be able to click buttons. Until last week this worked perfectly fine, but now I am not able to click buttons during presentations on my Laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad E540). The presentation will just jump to the next slide, thus the app is not focused. But this still works on my colleague's laptop (Asus Vivobook S400C). We use the same versions of Powerpoint (2016) and Windows (10). Rolling back to older versions of our code did not work as well.

Is there any setting in Powerpoint that could be responsible for this issue or is there any way to make this possible using the office.js API?

Edit:
Lenovo Laptop PowerPoint Version: 16.0.7726.1042 (64 Bit)
Asus Laptop Powerpoint Version: 16.0.8201.2102 (32 Bit)

Do you believe I shoud just wait until I am able to update to a higher version?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you add the complete version and build number (16.x.x.x) for the PowerPoint clients you're using? Office revs monthly so knowing the specific build numbers can often help track down what may be going on.

Comment: Sorry for updating so late! I edited my initial question.

Comment: Any more insights?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add a comment for this question. I have exactly the same problem and it also on Lenovo laptop, powerpoint 2016. When going to slide show, powerpoint just show an static image (the snapshot at the time entering presentation mode), so clicking on it just make it move the next slide instead of focusing on the addin.

Comment: Hi @J.Neumann, this problem is at microsoft side. They are working on it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561014/powerpoint-content-add-in-on-windows-just-show-an-image-in-slide-show-mode-inste

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a bug that has since been fixed. For more details, see [powerpoint-content-add-in-on-windows-just-show-an-image-in-slide-show-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561014/powerpoint-content-add-in-on-windows-just-show-an-image-in-slide-show-mode-inste)

Comment: Dear Rick, unfortunately this still does not work in our case. We have waited for an update of our PowerPoint Version to be sure. Our current versions are 16.0.4639.1000 (other models than before) and 16.0.8431.2110 (updated version on Vivobook). But still, everytime we enter presentation mode, a click on the app just leads to a jump to the next slide.