# Powerpoint content add-in on Windows just show an image in slide show mode instead of a web app

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, office-js, office-addins

I developed a powerpoint content addin and it works fine on Mac. Then I test it on Windows and found out that when I go to slide show mode, Powerpoint just show an image (a snapshot at the time entering to slide mode) instead of a web app. There is no interaction to the addin on slide show mode, clicking on it just make it move to the next slide. The addin works fine in edit mode though.

Strangely, this behaviour is not the same for all Powerpoint (2016) on Windows. I tested on another Windows laptop and everything works just fine. So I wonder if there is a settings or something for this, but I cannot figure out.

My addin shows the data changing overtime, animation, etc, so showing a static image is just useless.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are the build numbers of the PowerPoint 2016 where it works and the one where it doesn't?

Comment: @RickKirkham they are both 1704 ( Build 8067.2115), but it works on Asus while on Lenovo it doesn't. So far for windows, I just tested on these 2 models. Other Mac laptops works fine.

Comment: I tested on a Dell with PowerPoint 2013, it also shows an image in slide show mode.

Comment: Our engineers are puzzled and have asked for additional information: 1) Windows version and Office version (O365 or standalone version) and build number
2) Do all content add-ins show as image in presenting mode or just your add-in?
3) Where is the add-in manifest hosted? Share Folder? Or SharePoint catalog?
4) Can you share the app manifest so we can test it?

Comment: Another user (without commenting privileges on SO) has reported that he is seeing the same symptoms on laptops with version Office version: 1707 (Build: 8326.2076 Click-to-Run) (both 32-bit and 64-bit). But it is working on a laptop with version 1707 (Build: 8326.2052 Click-to-Run) 64-bit. The laptop where it's working is a Lenovo and all but one of the laptops where it is not working are exactly the same model of Lenovo.

Comment: More info from the 2nd user: (1) When the laptop where it works was updated to the same version as those where it doesn't work, it STILL WORKS. (2) Everything works in all machines in PowerPoint reading view. (3) If we have a secondary display connected to the notebook and we are in PowerPoint's full screen slide show mode on the primary display, then the web content of our content panes appear on the secondary display, misplaced and offset from its original position, floating above everything else. These misplaced web contents on the secondary display are responsive to mouse hover action.

Comment: A suggestion from the product team: a change that might help was made recently. To test is, sign up for Office Insider on one of the machines where it is not working. Update the machine to the latest Insider version and see if that fixes it. The sign-up page is: https://products.office.com/en-us/office-insider?tab=tab-1

Comment: I have been puzzled by this for a while (see old post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599227/the-add-in-window-is-converted-to-an-image?noredirect=1#comment86210864_49599227)). I got it to work for PPT `Win10, version 1805 (build 9330.2087)` but not on `Win 10, version 1708 (build 8431)`

Comment: This is still an issue impacting machines seemingly at random.  It impacts Microsoft's own WebViewer add-in as well, when it is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 3/28/18**

In response to the comments to this answer I've been in touch with the product team. It has now been determined that there is still an unfixed bug that causes these symptoms in some versions/builds/flight-configurations of PowerPoint. We are not able to provide an estimate of when it will be fixed. In the meantime, we cannot support interactive content add-ins in slide show mode in Windows.

**-- Original Answer Below --**

**Update 10/18/17:**

Just want to close the loop on this question.

It is possible for Office to behave differently on different computers even when the OS and Office version are the same, right down to the build number. Office pushes incremental code changes, called "flights", to desktop Office (Click-to-Run) approximately monthly **without raising the Office build number**.

Some of these flights are bug fixes. Others are experiments that are intentionally pushed to only some computers. Even in the case of bug fixes, the flights don't get pushed to all machines at the same time. It might take over a week for a flight to be pushed to all computers. (Strictly speaking, all computers with an Office build that supports the flight.)

The problem described in this question was a result of a bug in PowerPoint. A flight to fix it was deployed, but it had been pushed to only some of the OP's computers at the time (s)he posted the question. It has since been pushed to all computers.

Comment: What will be the behavoir when the fix has finally reached all customers: 
Will active addin content be supported in presentation mode or will we have a static screenshot of the addin? @Rick Kirkham

Comment: This should be fixed now on all machines with Office 2016 version 1704+ (Click-to-Run).

Comment: Some users still report this bug. Latest bug happens on Powerpoint 2016 (16.0.8431.2110) 32 bit, version 1708 (Build 8431.2153 Click-to-Run).

Comment: @RickKirkham Latest O365 - still no fix for this issue. Getting negative reviews in Store. Can you share any updates?

Comment: I'm investigating with the product team. In the meantime, what is the exact Office version and build number you are using?

Comment: @RickKirkham O365, Version 1708 (Build 8431.2215 Click-to-Run), Semi-annual Channel, Win 10 N x64 with media pack installed.

Comment: @RickKirkham Using PPT Version 1803 (Build 9126.2072 Click-To-Run) still NOT working. This is an anoying situation... our customers are still facing a static picture and we could NOT tell them what to do and when this fix will reach their machines!

Comment: @RickKirkham Any update on this? It has been 9 months and some users still report this bug.

Comment: @MyNguyen Please seem my updated answer as of today. Sorry, the news is bad.

Comment: @ndee Please see my updated answer as of today. Sorry the news is bad.

Comment: @ReVolly Please see my updated answer as of today. Sorry the news is bad.

Comment: @RickKirkham I have many users with this error. I am working with the Mentimeter Add-in. Latest user with this issue is using `Win 10, version 1708 (build 8431)`

Comment: @RickKirkham Do you have a specific list of versions or builds that have this bug? We need to update this to our clients.

Comment: @MyNguyen It is my understanding that builds before 1802 9126.2251 have the bug.